# Plotting 3-tuple data points in a surface / contour plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, rpy2, surface

I have some surface data that is generated by an external program as XYZ values. I want to create the following graphs, using matplotlib:

- Surface plot
- Contour plot
- Contour plot overlayed with a surface plot

I have looked at several examples for plotting surfaces and contours in matplotlib - however, the Z values seems to be a function of X and Y  i.e. Y ~ f(X,Y).

I assume that I will somehow need to transform my Y variables, but I have not seen any example yet, that shows how to do this.

So, my question is this: given a set of (X,Y,Z) points, how may I generate Surface and contour plots from that data?

BTW, just to clarify, I do NOT want to create scatter plots. Also although I mentioned matplotlib in the title, I am not averse to using rpy(2), if that will allow me to create these charts.

Comment: I posted an example for how to put the data into 2-D arrays to be able to use matplotlib's surface plot: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30539444/3585557.  Also, have a look at these related/similar/duplicate posts: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9170838/3585557, http://stackoverflow.com/q/12423601/3585557, http://stackoverflow.com/q/21161884/3585557, http://stackoverflow.com/q/26074542/3585557, http://stackoverflow.com/q/28389606/3585557, http://stackoverflow.com/q/29547687/3585557

Answer (score 25, accepted):

for do a **contour plot** you need interpolate your data to a regular grid http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Gridding_irregularly_spaced_data

a quick example:

```
>>> xi = linspace(min(X), max(X))
>>> yi = linspace(min(Y), max(Y))
>>> zi = griddata(X, Y, Z, xi, yi)
>>> contour(xi, yi, zi)
```

for the **surface** http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.html

```
>>> from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
>>> fig = figure()
>>> ax = Axes3D(fig)
>>> xim, yim = meshgrid(xi, yi)
>>> ax.plot_surface(xim, yim, zi)
>>> show()

>>> help(meshgrid(x, y))
    Return coordinate matrices from two coordinate vectors.
    [...]
    Examples
    --------
    >>> X, Y = np.meshgrid([1,2,3], [4,5,6,7])
    >>> X
    array([[1, 2, 3],
           [1, 2, 3],
           [1, 2, 3],
           [1, 2, 3]])
    >>> Y
    array([[4, 4, 4],
           [5, 5, 5],
           [6, 6, 6],
           [7, 7, 7]])
```

**contour in 3D** http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/mplot3d/contour3d_demo.html

```
>>> fig = figure()
>>> ax = Axes3D(fig)
>>> ax.contour(xi, yi, zi) # ax.contourf for filled contours
>>> show()
```

Comment: +1 for the snippet. That helps a lot. Could you please explain the variables (xim and yim) you used in surface snippet? I cant see them defined anywhere.

Comment: xim and yim have coordinate matrices from xi and yi. I edited the answer to add a few fragments of help(meshgrid)

Comment: What if the data is already on a lattice, but just formatted as three columns, X, Y, and Z. Is there a simple pythonic way of transforming that to an imshow / contour plot compatible format?

Answer (score 2):

With pandas and numpy to import and manipulate data, with matplot.pylot.contourf to plot the image

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata

PATH='/YOUR/CSV/FILE'
df=pd.read_csv(PATH)

#Get the original data
x=df['COLUMNNE']
y=df['COLUMNTWO']
z=df['COLUMNTHREE']

#Through the unstructured data get the structured data by interpolation
xi = np.linspace(x.min()-1, x.max()+1, 100)
yi = np.linspace(y.min()-1, y.max()+1, 100)
zi = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi, interp='linear')

#Plot the contour mapping and edit the parameter setting according to your data (http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=contourf#matplotlib.pyplot.contourf)
CS = plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi, 5, levels=[0,50,100,1000],colors=['b','y','r'],vmax=abs(zi).max(), vmin=-abs(zi).max())
plt.colorbar()

#Save the mapping and save the image
plt.savefig('/PATH/OF/IMAGE.png')
plt.show()
```

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4EMb.png)

Answer (score 1):

Contour plot with rpy2 + ggplot2:

```
from rpy2.robjects.lib.ggplot2 import ggplot, aes_string, geom_contour
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import DataFrame

# Assume that data are in a .csv file with three columns X,Y,and Z
# read data from the file
dataf = DataFrame.from_csv('mydata.csv')

p = ggplot(dataf) + \
    geom_contour(aes_string(x = 'X', y = 'Y', z = 'Z'))
p.plot()
```

Surface plot with rpy2 + lattice:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import DataFrame
from rpy2.robjects import Formula

lattice = importr('lattice')
rprint = robjects.globalenv.get("print")

# Assume that data are in a .csv file with three columns X,Y,and Z
# read data from the file
dataf = DataFrame.from_csv('mydata.csv')

p = lattice.wireframe(Formula('Z ~ X * Y'), shade = True, data = dataf)
rprint(p)
```