# Plotting 3-D surfaces and lines with perspective

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I'm trying to plot a line through a 3-D surface as a means of indicating the axis. However, this only results in the line being plotted entirely on top of or beneath the surface--changing the `zorder` does not solve this.

What I'm looking for is for the line to appear as if it were piercing through the surface

My code and output are below:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,9))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(X,Z,Y,
                linewidth=0,
                cmap=cm.jet,
                facecolors=cm.jet(r_3d/max(abs(r_3d.flatten()))),
                edgecolor='none',
                shade=False,
                antialiased=False)

ax.plot([0,0],[-0.3,0.3],[0,0],linewidth=2,c='k')
```

Example of line plotted on top of surface

[image: Example of line plotted on top of surface]

Hand drawn example of my desired output

[image: Hand drawn example of my desired output]

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932150/matplotlib-wrong-overlapping-when-plotting-two-3d-surfaces-on-the-same-axes/43004221#43004221

Comment: @JohanC thank you! I think MayaVi is exactly what I need here

Comment: If you added the X,Y,Z of your input to the surface that would help us in recreating the output.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this with `zorder` (example [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html)), though I have not tried specifically with a 3d plot. `zorder` changes the plotting order, or essentially the depth at which specific items are plotted. Large z orders plot on top and small ones plot in the back, so if you make the 3d item a z order of 1 and the line as z order zero that should work.

Comment: Changing the ```zorder``` is basically an all or nothing switch--either the line is plotted entirely in front of or behind the surface when changing ```zorder```

Comment: The idea with `zorder` would be to split your surface: at the back draw the complete surface, then draw the line, and then draw the half of the surface that is closest to the viewer.  But I think `plot_surface` is not very happy with drawing half surfaces.

Comment: You could also just draw one complete 3d surface, and two lines.