# How to draw a flat 3D rectangle in matplotlib?

Tags: python

How do I draw a rectangle in 3D ? The code below works but it draws a triangle

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
x = [0,1,1,0]
y = [0,0,1,1]
z = [0,1,0,1]
verts = [list(zip(x,y,z))]
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts))
plt.show()
```

I tried adding a 4th corner but I get an error

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
x = [0,1,1,0]
y = [0,0,1,1]
z = [0,1,0,1]
a = [0,1,0,1]
verts = [list(zip(x,y,z,a))]
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts))
plt.show()
```

Is there a function that accepts 4 3D-coordinates then draws a flat rectangle? e.g.

`ax.draw_rectangle3d(tl=[0,0,0],tr=[0,0,1],bl=[0,1,0],br=[0,1,1])`

This function [Adding a Rectangle Patch and Text Patch to 3D Collection in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66738036/adding-a-rectangle-patch-and-text-patch-to-3d-collection-in-matplotlib) draws a flat rectangle but it does not allow me to set my own x,y,z coordinate and the rectangle is projected onto the axes.

Answer (score 2):

The Z axis is wrong should be [0,0,0,0], since each column is a point and the rectangle is on the 0 on Z axis.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
x = [0,1,1,0]
y = [0,0,1,1]
z = [0,0,0,0]
verts = [list(zip(x,y,z))]
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts))
plt.show()
```

You can use this to plot multiple surfaces.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

x = [0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,0]
y = [0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,1]
z = [0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1]

surfaces = []

for i in range(len(x)):
    surfaces.append( [list(zip(x[i],y[i],z[i]))] )

for surface in surfaces:
    ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(surface))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection, Line3DCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
points = np.array([[-1, -1, -1],
                  [1, -1, -1 ],
                  [1, 1, -1],
                  [-1, 1, -1],
                  [-1, -1, 1],
                  [1, -1, 1 ],
                  [1, 1, 1],
                  [-1, 1, 1]])
Z = points
Z = 10.0*Z
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
r = [-1,1]
X, Y = np.meshgrid(r, r)
ax.scatter3D(Z[:, 0], Z[:, 1], Z[:, 2])
verts = [[Z[0],Z[1],Z[2],Z[3]],
 [Z[4],Z[5],Z[6],Z[7]],
 [Z[0],Z[1],Z[5],Z[4]],
 [Z[2],Z[3],Z[7],Z[6]],
 [Z[1],Z[2],Z[6],Z[5]],
 [Z[4],Z[7],Z[3],Z[0]]]
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts, facecolors='cyan', linewidths=1, edgecolors='r', alpha=.20))

plt.show()
```