# various 2d plots in a 3d frame in python

Tags: python, matplotlib-3d

I want to plot 2d arrays that intersect in different planes in a 3d frame. I explain more

I have 2 sets of velocity fields, components in (x,z) and (y,z)

I would like to plot this in a 3d frame so i can use the velocity field in xz as 'base' and intersect perpendicularly this "surface" at a certain offset in x with the velocity field in yz.

Is this possible to do in python? or am I just better off creating the plots separately and integrating them elsewhere?

A little example of what I'm trying to do[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible using matplotlib.

I was originally going to suggest adapting the [3D Box Surface Plot example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/box3d.html#d-box-surface-plot) from the official examples gallery, by using `ax.plot_surface` instead of `ax.contourf`.
The issue you run into when doing this is that matplotlib does not handle overlapping/intersecting 3D surfaces well, as is discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932150/matplotlib-wrong-overlapping-when-plotting-two-3d-surfaces-on-the-same-axes). It suggests some using [Mayavi](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/examples.html) as an alternative, however I am not familiar with this library, so I cannot really help..

[image: janky overlapping]

For reference, the code I adapted from the matplotlib example :

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

import numpy as np

# Define dimensions
Nx, Ny, Nz = 100, 300, 500
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(Nx), np.arange(Ny), -np.arange(Nz))

# Create fake data
data = (((X+100)**2 + (Y-20)**2 + 2*Z)/1000+1)
dmin = data.min()
dptp = data.ptp()


def colorize(d, cmap=cm.viridis):
    shape = d.shape
    return cmap(((d-dmin)/dptp).flatten()).reshape((*shape, 4))


# Create a figure with 3D ax
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')


# Plot contour surfaces
C = ax.plot_surface(
    X[:, :, Nz//2], Y[:, :, Nz//2], Z[:, :, Nz//2],
    facecolors=colorize(data[:, :, Nz//2]),
    shade=False,
)
_ = ax.plot_surface(
    X[:, Nx//3, :], Y[:, Nx//3, :], Z[:, Nx//3, :],
    facecolors=colorize(data[:, Nx//3, :]),
    shade=False,
)
_ = ax.plot_surface(
    X[:, 2*Nx//3, :], Y[:, 2*Nx//3, :], Z[:, 2*Nx//3, :],
    facecolors=colorize(data[:, 2*Nx//3, :]),
    shade=False,
)
# --


# Set limits of the plot from coord limits
xmin, xmax = X.min(), X.max()
ymin, ymax = Y.min(), Y.max()
zmin, zmax = Z.min(), Z.max()
ax.set(xlim=[xmin, xmax], ylim=[ymin, ymax], zlim=[zmin, zmax])


# Set labels and zticks
ax.set(
    xlabel='X [km]',
    ylabel='Y [km]',
    zlabel='Z [m]',
    zticks=[0, -150, -300, -450],
)


# Show Figure
plt.show()
```

Comment: Yeah, the overlapping problem is something that I noticed after a couple of tries from my side. Looks like I will have to dig deeper to see if i find a solution. I'll post if I find a way to do this.