# Matplotlib's 3D Graph does not show anything

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib

I want to make a 3D Graph with Matplotlib. The graph window appears, but no data is shown. What am I doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = [0, 10, 20, 40, 100]
y = [1, 4, 8, 60, 200]
z = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]


ax.plot_surface(x, y, z)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plot_surface` expects 2D inputs ([doc](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot_surface)).  It is not plotting anything because you did not give it a valid surface to draw.

See this [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/subplot3d_demo.html).

Answer (score 0):

X, Y and Z needs to be **2D-arrays** :

> Surface plots Axes3D.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, *args, **kwargs) Create a
> surface plot.
>
> Argument  Description
>
> X, Y, Z   Data values as 2D arrays

However I do not understand the logic behind it : check this [SO pos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170838/surface-plots-in-matplotlib)t for more info.

Comment: the logic is that `plot_surface` and the underlying functions assume that the connectivity of the points in the surface are given by the position in the matrix.  This is `X[i,j]` has as NN `X[i + 1, j]`, `X[i, j + 1]`, `X[i, j - 1]`, and `X[i - 1, j]`