# Surface plot with matplotlib, Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a `nx3` array, lets call it `data`, where I want the first 2 columns to be `x` and `y` coordinates and the 3rd column to be a `z` coordinate associated with the `x` and `y` coordinates in the same row.

I now want to draw a surface plot where the surface intersects all the `z` coordinates.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170838/surface-plots-in-matplotlib) post but cannot figure it out.

I know that I can use matplotlib's `Axes3D` and`fig.gca(projection='3d')` and that it takes 3 `nxn` arrays, where I think the `X` and `Y` arrays can be obtained with `X,Y = np.meshgrid(data[:,0],data[:,1])`, but I am not sure how to obtain an `nxn` `Z` array if there is only 1 `Z` coordinate associated with each `x` and `y`.

Then, I would like to smoothen the surface, as I am sure a surface with only a few data points will look ugly, and I am only looking to represent the general shape of the data and specific values aren't too important. Thus, is there a way to interpolate between the data points in 2 dimensions to smoothen the graph?

Example data set:

```
data = np.array([[4260,150,116]
                 [4204,149,1070]
                 [4204,188,470]
                 [4444,140,389]
                 [3255,149,69]
                 [6370,149,1109]
                 [5765,189,3531]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
x, y, z = data[:,0], data[:,1], data[:,2]
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[min(x):max(x):50j, min(y):max(y):50j]
z = griddata((x, y), z, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')
```