# Plotting 3D surface from points coordinates in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to do something like this in matplotlib but not with points but with surface? (I have coordinates of points)

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#X = ...
#Y = ... Some coordinates points from file it is list
#Z = ...

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c='r')
ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [surface plots in matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170838/surface-plots-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You will have to use the `plot_surface` command from your `ax` object. I will present a code snippet from my own plotting library, you will just have to refactor it as needed. However, this (or highly similar) questions have been asked before (e.g. [surface plots in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9170838/1093485)).

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def surface_plot(X,Y,Z,**kwargs):
    """ WRITE DOCUMENTATION
    """
    xlabel, ylabel, zlabel, title = kwargs.get('xlabel',""), kwargs.get('ylabel',""), kwargs.get('zlabel',""), kwargs.get('title',"")
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z)
    ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
    ax.set_zlabel(zlabel)
    ax.set_title(title)
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

---

PS: There has been a recent string of down votes on this answer. Therefore I will add that the original question was badly formulated and that this answer is exactly what the OP wanted based on a private conversation with the OP.

Comment: Throws an error : `Argument Z must be 2-dimensional`

Comment: @mrgloom That is correct, the data you are using must not be in the correct format for surface_plot.

Comment: I would like to know why this got a downvote, years after being an accepted answer.

Comment: @BasJansen Since in your answer you assume every pair of (x_i, y_j) holds a corresponding Z value, which means Z is a 2D array. While the question is "from points coordinates", which means there is no 2D array for Z at all...

Comment: @Kite.Y There has to be a Z for each coordinate, otherwise it wouldn't be a surface plot.

Comment: @BasJansen Of course there should be a Z. The point is the coordinates (X,Y) might not be a grid, in which case you have a Nx3 arrays with N (x,y,z) coodinates, and Z is not a 2D-array --- that's the original question, though...

Comment: I support the down vote. The question asked for a coordinates based solution with the same interface as the `scatter` function. @BasJansen, you just provided a fancy way to call `plot_surface` which is not the same thing

Comment: The original question was badly formulated by the OP, the answer I gave was provided based on a private conversation with the OP and it did what the OP wanted. That's all that I will say versus all the 'recent' down votes on an accepted answer from years ago.