# Plotting a 3D surface with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot, data-visualization

I have empirical data obtained from an experiment. Each row of data in the dataframe consists of 12 'attributes' (columns).

I am particularly interested in studying the interrelation of three of the columns, as a precursor to carrying out further exploratory data analysis (EDA):

I would like to visualize the interrelationship between these attributes, by plotting a 3D surface plot.

Here is relevant information of the three attributes/columns:

```
column name:   data type
foo            real (float - but may want to map this to integer after further EDA)
foobar         real
foofoobar      integer
```

Given the following pseudocode, how may I plot a 3D surface plot of the columns foo (y axis), foobar (z axis), foofoobar (x axis)?

```
import pandas as pd

my_tuple_list = grok_experimental_data('/path/to/data/file.dat')
df = pd.DataFrame(my_tuple_list, columns = column_names)

# Now code to plot foo on y axis, foobar on z axis and foofoobar on x axis ...
```

Comment: There are plenty of potentially relevant answers on SO already...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to surface plot/3d plot from dataframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36589521/how-to-surface-plot-3d-plot-from-dataframe)