# How do I create a visual representation of a magnetic field in 3d in Python?

Tags: python, 3d

I'm trying to plot some data as a 3D image using python. i have taken all my data points down, so i have lots of x,y and z points and the intensity at that point. I cant find a way where i just put in at point x,y,z the intensity is T.  anyone any ideas? i think a scatter plot would be best but i don't know how to do this. I've only been learning python since September so i'm not very good. I have tried looking at the different scatter plots and wire mesh etc but they seem to be for lines, mathematical functions and the points are the result of a function, not just data points at a certain point in space. i'm at a loss.

Comment: Depending on the format your data is in: [3d plot pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36589521/198633), or the more generic [3d plot with matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html)

Comment: I got it working using matplotlib, Thank you