# matplotlib surface plot for (x-y)^2

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, mplot3d

Can anyone help me with plotting a 3D surface plot for the equation `f(x,y) = (x-y)^2`

The Z axis should represent the function f(x,y)

I have the below function:

```
def fnc(X):
    return (X[0] - X[1]) ** 2
```

Here X is a numpy array with first parameter as X and the second as Y.
I specifically need it to be this way. So please don't suggest me to change the signature. ;)

I tried the below from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170838/surface-plots-in-matplotlib) solution:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x = y = np.linspace(-5,5,100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = fnc1([np.linspace(-5,5,100) , np.linspace(-6,6,100)])
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')
plt.show()
```

However i get the wrong plot.

[image: This is a wrong plot though]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array `Z` to be plotted should be a 2D array, just like `X` and `Y` are 2D arrays, such that for each pair of values from `X` and `Y` you get exactly one point in `Z`. It therefore makes sense to use those arrays `X` and `Y` as input to your `fnc` function,  `Z = fnc([X,Y])`

The complete code would look like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


def fnc(X):
    return (X[0] - X[1]) ** 2

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=Axes3D.name)
x = y = np.linspace(-5,5,100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = fnc([X,Y])
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')
ax.view_init(elev=15, azim=-118)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your `fnc` is wrong. Get your surface just as `Z=(X-Y)**2`. It is the best solution because of all calculations of `Z` would be vectorized.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x = y = np.linspace(-5,5,100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = (X-Y)**2
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me how you got your perspective in the plot?

Comment: Rotate it by mouse

Comment: The function `fnc(X)` as it is in the question is clearly correct, why should it be wrong? It is also as "vectorized" as any other two argument function and has the same performance.