# Surface plot of rows

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a txt file that contains a matrix with `N` rows and `M` columns. I would like to create some sort of surface graph where I can see `N` different curves each one plotting all the elements in that row.

```
head output.txt

0.001194  0.001184  0.001499  0.002410  0.002337  0.002323  0.001685 0.01194
0.002260  0.002152  0.002390  0.001305  0.001270  0.001303  0.001155 0.01194
0.001232  0.002307  0.002127  0.001672  0.002278  0.002427  0.002136 0.01194
0.001950  0.001359  0.001137  0.001168  0.001208  0.001189  0.002564 0.01194   
0.002334  0.002345  0.002461  0.002223  0.002138  0.002352  0.001299 0.01194
0.001320  0.001184  0.001239  0.001466  0.002454  0.002349  0.002383 0.01194
```

The code I am currently using

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt('output.txt')

X = np.arange(len(data))
plt.plot(X, data)

plt.show()
```

But this is only producing a 2D plot.

I have also tried the following:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

nx = len(data)
ny = len(data[0])
x = range(nx)
y = range(ny)

hf = plt.figure()
ha = hf.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)  
ha.plot_surface(X, Y, data)
```

However this gives an error

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Comment: Could you add sample data to reproduce your example ?

Comment: @RobJan A small sample data has been added

Comment: You can possibly find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170838/surface-plots-in-matplotlib

Comment: @BossaNova Thanks! I got there before but it is not clear when you already have predefined data.

Comment: @Manolete where's your Z co-ordinate?

Comment: @gregory isn't `data` the `Z` coordinate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. The problem was in `nx` and `ny`.

```
nx = len(data[0])
ny = len(data)

x = range(nx)
y = range(ny)

hf = plt.figure()
ha = hf.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)  
ha.plot_surface(X, Y, data)
```

[image]