# 3D surface plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I want to create a 3D surface plot in python, but I am a little confused about how to do this. I have a single line, but I would like the program to plot all possible outputs using all je and be values. Any ideas? I need to find the cartesian product between je and be values, but I think there might be some built-in packages that already do this, but I don't know.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy as scipy
import math
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

jvals = [[(0.0), 0.0, 0.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
##########
##This creates the cartesian product of the two array
bvals = [0.1, 0.0, 0.0]
jevals = []
bevals = []
###########################
def Neuro(xyz, bvals, jvals): #redefine function 3 parameters
    re = xyz[0]
    rp = xyz[1]
    rs = xyz[2]

    b1 = bvals[0]
    b2 = bvals[1]
    b3 = bvals[2]

    Jee = jvals[0][0]
    Jep = jvals[0][1]
    Jes = jvals[0][2]

    Jpe = jvals[1][0]
    Jpp = jvals[1][1]
    Jps = jvals[1][2]

    Jse = jvals[2][0]
    Jsp = jvals[2][1]
    Jss = jvals[2][2]

    """
    Given:
       define ue up us
    """
#    print("Original jee value:", jvals[0][0], "and", bvals[0])
#    print(Jee, Jep, Jes, b1)
    u_e = (((Jee)*re)-((Jep)*rp)-((Jes)*rs)+b1)
    u_p = (((Jpe)*re)-((Jpp)*rp)-((Jps)*rs)+b2)
    u_s =  (Jse)*re + Jsp+ Jss + b3

    f_e = -re + (u_e) # add functions
    f_p = -rp + (u_p)
    f_s = -rs + (u_s)

    return f_e, f_p, f_s

############################################### Loop  ############################################
num_steps = 100
############################################### Eigen Values  ############################################
jevals = np.empty(num_steps)
bevals = np.empty(num_steps)
re = np.empty(num_steps)
rs = np.empty(num_steps)
rp = np.empty(num_steps)



############################################### GRAPHING/Loop ############################################

re[0], rp[0], rs[0] = (0.25,0.20,0.15)
##################Neuro Function loop
for i in range(num_steps):
    #Initializes Je and be
    jevals[i] = (0.01)*i
    bevals[i] = (0.01)*i
    jvals[0][0] = jevals[i]
    bvals[0] = bevals[i]
    xyz0 = np.array([1.0,1,1])
    ##FSOLVE
    xyz0 = np.array([1.0,1,1])
    xyz = fsolve(Neuro, xyz0,args = (bvals,jvals))
    re[i] =xyz[0::3]
    rp[i] =xyz[1::3]
    rs[i] =xyz[2::3]
ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel("Jee Values")
ax.set_ylabel("Be  Values")
ax.set_zlabel("Root Values")
ax.set_title("3D Plot")
ax.plot(jevals, bevals, re, 'r')
# ax.plot(jevals, bevals, rp, 'b')
# ax.plot(jevals, bevals, rs, 'g')
#print(jvals[0][0], bvals[0])
plt.show()
#plt.savefig("sim_roots_Jee"+str(jvals[0][0])+"_be"+str(bvals[0])+".png", format='png')
#print(re[i], rp[i], rp[i])
print(jevals[i], bevals[i])
# b_vals[i]
##################
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [surface plots in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170838/surface-plots-in-matplotlib)

Comment: kind of. I'm still confused because my loop creates jevals and bevals, and I don't know how I would use meshgrid with this. @wim

Comment: fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x = y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.05)
jevals, bevals = np.meshgrid(x, y)
# zs = np.array(fun(np.ravel(jevals), np.ravel(bevals)))
# Z = zs.reshape(X.shape)

ax.plot_surface(jevals, bevals, re)
ax.set_xlabel("Jee Values")
ax.set_ylabel("Be  Values")
ax.set_zlabel("Root Values")
ax.set_title("3D Plot")
# ax.plot(jevals, bevals, rp, 'b')
# ax.plot(jevals, bevals, rs, 'g')
#print(jvals[0][0], bvals[0])
plt.show()

Comment: I tried this, but this does not make sense because my function requires two inputs and I don't know how to make my output a two dimensional array.

Comment: @Woodford does that help