# Plotting BoTorch Synthetic functions

Tags: python, pytorch, botorch

I'm trying to plot the [Ackley synthetic function](https://botorch.org/api/test_functions.html#botorch.test_functions.synthetic.Ackley) from botorch (mainly to understand how it works and why if I feed it 2 tensors it only returns 1 value), and I'm facing a bunch of different problems. I've also tried other functions but with the same results... Any person able to shed some light over this topic will be welcome.

Here's the code I'm using:

```py
import numpy as np
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import botorch.test_functions.synthetic as funcs

#We only use Ackley for now
branin = funcs.Branin()
hartman = funcs.Hartmann()
ackley = funcs.Ackley()

x1 = np.linspace(0, 5, 2)
x2 = np.linspace(0, 5, 2)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x1,x2)
Z = ackley(torch.tensor([X,Y]))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection':'3d'})
surf = ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z)
```

The fun part is that with these settings, I'm able to plot it, but if I change the linspace so it has more points, the plotting part gives an error for shape mismatch...

Comment: You change the linspace how exactly?

Comment: I do a [meshgrid](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) to get all the possible combinations of x1 and x2

Comment: But I'm realizing this is not a problem with Ackley, it's more of a problem with the plot_surface function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about argument shaping, combining your code with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170838/surface-plots-in-matplotlib), got:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import botorch.test_functions.synthetic as funcs

#We only use Ackley for now
branin = funcs.Branin()
hartman = funcs.Hartmann()
ackley = funcs.Ackley()

x1 = np.linspace(-5, 5, 30)
x2 = np.linspace(-5, 5, 30)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x1,x2)
Z = ackley(torch.tensor([np.ravel(X),np.ravel(Y)]).T)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection':'3d'})
surf = ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z.reshape(X.shape))
```

Comment: It does work, although it gives a warning about creating a tensor from a list of `np.ndarrays` (easy to solve if you just add `torch.tensor(np.array([np.ravel(X),np.ravel(Y)]).T))`)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Alexey Birukov 's answer, a nice person in the [python discord](https://discord.gg/python) gave me this code, which also works and let's you see the inner workings of plot_surface as well as those of Ackley.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from botorch.test_functions import Ackley
import torch  # Import PyTorch

# Initialize the Ackley function from BoTorch
ackley = Ackley(dim=2, negate=True)

# Generate X and Y coordinates
x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)

# Create meshgrid
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Evaluate the Ackley function for each (x, y) pair
Z = np.zeros_like(X)
for i in range(X.shape[0]):
    for j in range(X.shape[1]):
        Z[i, j] = ackley.evaluate_true(torch.tensor([[X[i, j], Y[i, j]]], dtype=torch.float))

# Create plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Plot surface
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='viridis')

# Set labels and title
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_title('Ackley Function')

# Show plot
plt.show()
```