# Colored 3D plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, mplot3d

I found here this good [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423601/python-the-simplest-way-to-plot-3d-surface) to plot 3D data with Python 2.7.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np


# ======
## data:

DATA = np.array([
    [-0.807237702464, 0.904373229492, 111.428744443],
    [-0.802470821517, 0.832159465335, 98.572957317],
    [-0.801052795982, 0.744231916692, 86.485869328],
    [-0.802505546206, 0.642324228721, 75.279804677],
    [-0.804158144115, 0.52882485495, 65.112895758],
    [-0.806418040943, 0.405733109371, 56.1627277595],
    [-0.808515314192, 0.275100227689, 48.508994388],
    [-0.809879521648, 0.139140394575, 42.1027499025],
    [-0.810645106092, -7.48279012695e-06, 36.8668106345],
    [-0.810676720161, -0.139773175337, 32.714580273],
    [-0.811308686707, -0.277276065449, 29.5977405865],
    [-0.812331692291, -0.40975978382, 27.6210856615],
    [-0.816075037319, -0.535615685086, 27.2420699235],
    [-0.823691366944, -0.654350489595, 29.1823292975],
    [-0.836688691603, -0.765630198427, 34.2275056775],
    [-0.854984518665, -0.86845932028, 43.029581434],
    [-0.879261949054, -0.961799684483, 55.9594146815],
    [-0.740499820944, 0.901631050387, 97.0261463995],
    [-0.735011699497, 0.82881933383, 84.971061395],
    [-0.733021568161, 0.740454485354, 73.733621269],
    [-0.732821755233, 0.638770044767, 63.3815970475],
    [-0.733876941678, 0.525818698874, 54.0655910105],
    [-0.735055978521, 0.403303715698, 45.90859502],
    [-0.736448900325, 0.273425879041, 38.935709456],
    [-0.737556181137, 0.13826504904, 33.096106049],
    [-0.738278724065, -9.73058423274e-06, 28.359664343],
    [-0.738507612286, -0.138781586244, 24.627237837],
    [-0.738539663773, -0.275090412979, 21.857410904],
    [-0.739099040189, -0.406068448513, 20.1110519655],
    [-0.741152200369, -0.529726022182, 19.7019157715],
])


Xs = DATA[:,0]    
Ys = DATA[:,1]    
Zs = DATA[:,2]


## plot:    
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

surf = ax.plot_trisurf(Xs, Ys, Zs, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0)
fig.colorbar(surf)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(5))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(6))
ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(5))

fig.tight_layout()


fig.savefig('3D.png')
plt.show()
```

The result is good:

[image: Output]

But, could it be possible to put this 3D map "in 2D"? I want to have only the color as the indication for the Z coordinate. As it would be to see this plot "from the top".
And to notice, the data (and so z coordinate) come from a measurement, not a function.

I have a lot of data and my computer is very slow...

Comment: Have you looked into `plt.pcolormesh` or `plt.contourf`? Here's an example of their usage http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/pcolormesh_levels.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you can use a contour. Since you are already using a triangulation, you can use `tricontourf`. See an example below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np



## data:

DATA = np.array([
    [-0.807237702464, 0.904373229492, 111.428744443],
    [-0.802470821517, 0.832159465335, 98.572957317],
    [-0.801052795982, 0.744231916692, 86.485869328],
    [-0.802505546206, 0.642324228721, 75.279804677],
    [-0.804158144115, 0.52882485495, 65.112895758],
    [-0.806418040943, 0.405733109371, 56.1627277595],
    [-0.808515314192, 0.275100227689, 48.508994388],
    [-0.809879521648, 0.139140394575, 42.1027499025],
    [-0.810645106092, -7.48279012695e-06, 36.8668106345],
    [-0.810676720161, -0.139773175337, 32.714580273],
    [-0.811308686707, -0.277276065449, 29.5977405865],
    [-0.812331692291, -0.40975978382, 27.6210856615],
    [-0.816075037319, -0.535615685086, 27.2420699235],
    [-0.823691366944, -0.654350489595, 29.1823292975],
    [-0.836688691603, -0.765630198427, 34.2275056775],
    [-0.854984518665, -0.86845932028, 43.029581434],
    [-0.879261949054, -0.961799684483, 55.9594146815],
    [-0.740499820944, 0.901631050387, 97.0261463995],
    [-0.735011699497, 0.82881933383, 84.971061395],
    [-0.733021568161, 0.740454485354, 73.733621269],
    [-0.732821755233, 0.638770044767, 63.3815970475],
    [-0.733876941678, 0.525818698874, 54.0655910105],
    [-0.735055978521, 0.403303715698, 45.90859502],
    [-0.736448900325, 0.273425879041, 38.935709456],
    [-0.737556181137, 0.13826504904, 33.096106049],
    [-0.738278724065, -9.73058423274e-06, 28.359664343],
    [-0.738507612286, -0.138781586244, 24.627237837],
    [-0.738539663773, -0.275090412979, 21.857410904],
    [-0.739099040189, -0.406068448513, 20.1110519655],
    [-0.741152200369, -0.529726022182, 19.7019157715],
])


Xs = DATA[:,0]    
Ys = DATA[:,1]    
Zs = DATA[:,2]


## plot:    
fig = plt.figure()
contour = plt.tricontourf(Xs, Ys, Zs, cmap="YlGnBu_r")
fig.colorbar(contour)
fig.savefig('3D.png')
plt.show()
```

The results is

[image]

Comment: How could I change the color. I tried to change cmap="YlGnBu_r" by cmap="rgb" but I did not succeed. 
Basically I would like to have color going from red for high value to blue for the lowest one.

Comment: If you're talking about the colormap that you used above, it's called "jet" or "rainbow" ("jet" in Matplotlib), you might want to read [this](http://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html) and check [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) for the available options. I used a different colormap because it's better for the purpose of your contour plot, you can check [this](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/how-bad-is-your-colormap/) on why jet is a bad choice. And [this answer](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/19559/9667), regarding the use of colormaps.