# Building a surface from a scatter plot in 3D where [x,y] in 2D is transformed to [f1(x,y),f2(x,y),f3(x,y)]

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, matlab-figure

My data is generated by transforming 2D points on a grid to representation in 3D. Say, for example, I have some points [x,y] on a 2D grid and I transform it into a 3D representation like [x*cos(y), x*sin(y), y]. So I now have a bunch of 3D points. How would I get a surface plot of this 3D representation? I have access to the 2D representation as well.

A solution in either python/Matlab works fine for me.

Thank you!

Edit: The question was marked duplicate but it is not as per explanation below. The question for reference: [Creating a 3D surface plot from three 1D arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51152043/creating-a-3d-surface-plot-from-three-1d-arrays) .
The duplicate marked question assumes that in the [x,y,z] coordinates, the points can be expressed as [x,y,f(x,y)]. That is not the case in my problem. I have 2D points [x,y] and their corresponding 3D representation [f1(x,y),f2(x,y),f3(x,y)]. I provide this image below as an example as to what I want.

[image: Swiss Roll Manifold]

I have a bunch of scattered data points like on the right. From that, I want to generate an image on the left.

Image Credits: Fig. 1 from the paper - *Mekuz, Nathan, and John K. Tsotsos. "Parameterless Isomap with adaptive neighborhood selection." Joint Pattern Recognition Symposium. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg, 2006.*

Comment: In MATLAB: (1) **before** you apply the 2d->3D transformation, use `griddata` to reinterpolate your `z` values over a uniformly sampled `x,y` grid. (2) Fit or make a surface out of your points (which shouldn't be wrapped at this point). (3) apply the transformation on the `XData/YData/ZData` of the surface (the surface will transform (change shape) but will stay a `surface`).

Comment: @Hoki the question is open now, you should answer it.

Comment: You should provide sample data (a small reduced one please) and also explicit the "transformation" you apply to the set of points. Without data the only advice we can give is as I've done above, just a sequence of instructions.