# Plotting Poly3DCollection using add_collection3d

Tags: matplotlib, 3d, light

I have tree arrays of the same size representing the spherical coordinates of points in space. I want to plot them transformed in cartesian coordinates. I am trying to produce a surface and I need to use the `add_collection3d` method instead of the `plot_surface` because of the dimensions of my arrays. The original arrays have different lengths in spherical coordinates and the transformation into cartesian is not linear.

A simplified example follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LightSource
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


phi_rad = np.linspace(0,360, 10)/180.0*np.pi
theta_rad = np.linspace(0,360, 10)/180.0*np.pi # cos(theta)
counts_str = np.linspace(0, 100, 10) # counts

# convertion to cartesian coordinates 1D arrays
x = counts_str * np.sin(theta_rad) * np.cos(phi_rad)
y = counts_str * np.sin(theta_rad) * np.sin(phi_rad)
z_str = counts_str * np.cos(theta_rad)

verts = [list(zip(x, y, z_str))]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts, cmap="hot", alpha=0.9))
ls = LightSource(azdeg=225.0, altdeg=45.0)

ax.set_xlim3d(x.min(), x.max())
ax.set_ylim3d(y.min(), y.max())
ax.set_zlim3d(z_str.min(), z_str.max())

plt.show()
```

I would like to apply a `cmap` and a `LightSource` (don't affect the plot), as well as an `antialiased` because in my real data z is an array with 20000 elements.

Looking forward to hearing from your collective intelligence!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: reshape all the three vectors and use surface plot!

[Creating a 3D surface plot from three 1D arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51152043/creating-a-3d-surface-plot-from-three-1d-arrays/)