# 3D surface/volume plot of list

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, multidimensional-array, mayavi

I would like to represent a set of 3D points as a surface. The points are in an array format for x, y, z. I managed to plot the points in 3D in a sub-optimal solution by adding an array c which just contains 1's for each (x,y,z). There's surely a better solution for that already. What I want to do now is connect the points somehow and fill out a volume which contains these points in 3D.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8])
y = np.array([15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,21,21,21,15,15,15,15,15,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,26,26,17,17,18,18,18,18,18,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,30,30,30,30,30,20,20,20,21,21,21,21,21,21,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,22,23,23,23,23,24,24,24,24,24,24,24])
z = np.array([5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,9,10,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
c = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

img = ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=c)
plt.show()
```

This is what I get:

[image: My output]

What I approximately try to get:

[image: What I want]

So basically I'm looking for something that encloses all my points.
I hope this is not a duplicate, at least I did not find any answer that worked out for me.

Edit: Just added Mayavi to the tags, since I'm trying to find a workaround with the package.

Comment: Have a look at these https://stackoverflow.com/q/12423601/8878627

Comment: Thanks @SPSharan, I tried the solutions provided in the link. Unfortunately, they give me very weird looking outputs that I cannot quite interpret: [link](https://ibb.co/cXbZRt8). I was more expecting something boxy when looking at my points in 3D.