# Python contour plot in traditional 3D data?

Tags: python, function, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I've been using Python/NumPy for a lot of things for a while now, but I am still confused about creating 3D plots.

In a "traditional" data analysis program (Origin, SigmaPlot, Excel...), if you want to make a 3D plot or a contour plot, you usually have your data in `(X,Y,Z)` format, that is, for each pair of `X` and `Y` you have one value of `Z`.

As opposed to this, all Python plotting guides I find use `numpy.meshgrid` for plotting -and I don't fully understand the connection to the traditional plotting software.

Let's say I have the following code:

```
axes_range = np.linspace(-5, 5, num=25)

alphas = []

for xcoord in axes_range:
    for ycoord in axes_range:
        alphas.append(f(xcoord,ycoord))
```

What's the best way of making a plot of `(xcoord, ycoord, alphas)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate [Simplest way to plot 3d surface given 3d points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423601/simplest-way-to-plot-3d-surface-given-3d-points)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simplest way to plot 3d surface given 3d points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423601/simplest-way-to-plot-3d-surface-given-3d-points)

Answer (score 0):

With matplotlib you simply need

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm

X, Y = np.meshgrid(xcoord, ycoord)
plt.contourf(X, Y, alphas.T, levels=20, cmap=cm.jet)
plt.show()
```

I think you need to transpose `alphas` as I do here.

Comment: That would be nice, but apparently you get TypeError: Input z must be 2D, not 1D - so it's not enough to just transpose alphas

Comment: Then reshape it,
`alphas = alphas.reshape((len(xcoord), len(ycoord)))`