# 3D plot of a list of lists of values

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I'm trying to make a 3d plot from a list of lists of values. All the sublists have the same number of values.

I tried this: [Plot a 3d surface from a 'list of lists' using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919903/plot-a-3d-surface-from-a-list-of-lists-using-matplotlib) , but I get the error:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shap
```

Here is how to reproduce:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

list_of_lists = [[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],[2,3,5,9,2,3,5,9,2,3,5,9],[5,9,8,1,5,9,8,1,5,9,8,1],[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],[2,3,5,9,2,3,5,9,2,3,5,9],[5,9,8,1,5,9,8,1,5,9,8,1]]

data = np.array(list_of_lists)
length = data.shape[0]
width = data.shape[1]
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(length), np.arange(width))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x, y, data)
plt.show()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to default cartesian indexing of `meshgrid` output (see [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) for more info) your `data` has shape of (6, 12), but `x` and `y` have shapes of (12, 6). The easiest way to solve the problem is to transpose `data` array:

```
ax.plot_surface(x, y, data.T)
```

Or you can apply matrix indexing notation to `meshgrid` output:

```
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(length), np.arange(width), indexing='ij')
```