# 3d surface plots not showing

Tags: python, matplotlib, surface, matplotlib-3d

I am trying to make a simple 3D surface plot with matplotlib but the plot does not show at the end; I only get empty 3D axes.

Here is what I did:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x = np.arange(1, 100, 1)
y = np.arange(1, 100, 1)
z = np.arange(1, 100, 1)

fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=5, cstride=5) 
show()
```

...and I get this:
[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at these related/similar/duplicate posts: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3012783/3585557, http://stackoverflow.com/q/9170838/3585557, http://stackoverflow.com/q/12423601/3585557, http://stackoverflow.com/q/21161884/3585557, http://stackoverflow.com/q/26074542/3585557, http://stackoverflow.com/q/28389606/3585557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not plotting a surface: `x`, `y` and `z` needs to be 2D arrays. Look at this example: http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.html.

Comment: Thanks! but it seems that Z must be a function of X and Y. What if the three of them are independent variables?

Comment: Z can be independent of X and Y. That does not prevent you from plotting them. For example, `X = np.arange(-5,5,0.25); X,Y = np.meshgrid(X,X); Z = np.random.random(X.shape);`. However, X, Y and Z must have the same size.

Comment: OK. You're right. I think surface plots are not the ideal way to show my data. Probably because the variables are independent, the figure came out looking weird.

Comment: Do you still know your final code Libabah?

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d, Axes3D
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

x= np.arange(1, 100, 1)
y= np.arange(1, 100, 1)
z= np.arange(1, 100, 1)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
xi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 50)
yi = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 50)
zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi[None, :], yi[:, None]), method='nearest')    # create a uniform spaced grid
xig, yig = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
surf = ax.plot_wireframe(X=xig, Y=yig, Z=zi, rstride=5, cstride=3, linewidth=1)   # 3d plot
plt.show()
```

[image]